# How to get selected item of NSOutlineView without using NSTreeController?

Tags: cocoa, pyobjc

How do I get the selected item of an NSOutlineView with using my own data source.
I see I can get selectedRow but it returns a row ID relative to the state of the outline. The only way to do it is to track the expanded collapsed state of the items, but that seems ridiculous.

I was hoping for something like:

```
array = [outlineViewOutlet selectedItems];
```

I looked at the other similar questions, they dont seem to answer the question.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this and is trying to find an answer for swift, this is a port of the below code.            `println(MainOutlineList.itemAtRow(MainOutlineList.selectedRow))`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`NSOutlineView` inherits from `NSTableView`, so you get nice methods such as `selectedRow`:

```
id selectedItem = [outlineView itemAtRow:[outlineView selectedRow]];
```

Comment: Thank you SO much that works just as intended. I wish it was easier to find it in the Apple docs...

Comment: Great ! and so simple !

Comment: It returns -1 for selected row, can you guide im missing something?

Comment: @Xander that would mean nothing is selected (`-1` is `NSNotFound`).

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

NSOutlineView has a delegate method `outlineViewSelectionDidChange`

```
 func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

    // Get the outline view from notification object
    guard let outlineView = notification.object as? NSOutlineView else {return}

    // Here you can get your selected item using selectedRow
    if let item = outlineView.item(atRow: outlineView.selectedRow) {
      
    }
}
```

**Bonus Tip**: You can also get the `parent item` of the selected item like this:

```
func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

// Get the outline view from notification object
guard let outlineView = notification.object as? NSOutlineView else {return}

// Here you can get your selected item using selectedRow
if let item = outlineView.item(atRow: outlineView.selectedRow) {
  
     // Get the parent item
      if let parentItem = outlineView.parent(forItem: item){
            
      }  
   } 
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave De Long: excellent answer, here is the translation to Swift 3.0

```
@objc private func onItemClicked() {
    if let item = outlineView.item(atRow: outlineView.clickedRow) as? FileSystemItem {
        print("selected item url: \(item.fileURL)")
    }
}
```

Shown is a case where item is from class FileSystemItem with a property fileURL.